# Ldap Authentication - Always returns invalid credentials

Tags: authentication, ldap

i have a problem with ldap configuration on a centos. I have to setup a ldap configuration, which allows access to directories via web for specific users.
I have already look through other questions and answer about this topic, without finding a solution.

This is my ldap configuration:

```
LDAPVerifyServerCert Off

<Location "/users">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Authentication required"
 AuthBasicProvider ldap
 AuthLDAPURL ldaps://hosta/ou=People,dc=lab,dc=local?uid
 AuthLDAPBindDN uid=ApacheUser,ou=ServiceUser,dc=lab,dc=local
 AuthLDAPBindPassword {SSHA}KS9kGBfWdnC8NrXmFEOxzaYDNZbD2BNj
 Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The directory users has read access for all users/groups and as owner root.

When I tried to connect via webbrowser, I always receive the following errormessage:

```
 [Sat Dec 27 12:42:11.500241 2014] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 2163] mod_authnz_ldap.c(501): [client 192.168.56.1:52161] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldaps://hosta/dc=local,dc=lab,ou=People?uid
[Sat Dec 27 12:42:11.500415 2014] [ldap:debug] [pid 2163] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.
[Sat Dec 27 12:42:11.515868 2014] [authnz_ldap:info] [pid 2163] [client 192.168.56.1:52161] AH01695: auth_ldap authenticate: user joe authentication failed; URI /users/ [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed][Invalid credentials]
[Sat Dec 27 12:42:11.515910 2014] [auth_basic:error] [pid 2163] [client 192.168.56.1:52161] AH01617: user joe: authentication failure for "/users/": Password Mismatch
```

But the credentials are definitely correct, which are used.

With ldapsearch I receive the following result for joe:
 ldapsearch -H ldaps://hosta -D uid=ApacheUser,ou=ServiceUser,dc=lab,dc=local -b uid=joe,ou=People,dc=lab,dc=local -W

```
Enter LDAP Password:
 # extended LDIF
 #
 # LDAPv3
 # base <uid=joe,ou=People,dc=lab,dc=local> with scope subtree
 # filter: (objectclass=*)
 # requesting: ALL
 #

 # joe, People, lab.local dn: uid=joe,ou=People,dc=lab,dc=local objectClass: person objectClass: inetOrgPerson objectClass:
 organizationalPerson objectClass: posixAccount cn: Joe Everyman
 uidNumber: 1010 gidNumber: 99 homeDirectory: /home/joe loginShell:
 /bin/bash sn: Everyman givenName: Joe uid: joe userPassword::
 e1NTSEF9S1M5a0dCZldkbkM4TnJYbUZFT3h6YVlETlpiRDJCTmo=

 # search result search: 2 result: 0 Success

 # numResponses: 2
 # numEntries: 1
```

I hope you could give me a hint, what is wrong with my configuration.

br 
Michael

Comment: Have you tried the configuration with the AuthLDAPBindPassword value in plain? I've seen other instances where people have commented that using hashed values do not work during LDAP binding.

Comment: Thx! That was the solution!

Comment: You might try adding quotes to AuthLDAPURL